# How can I save NSMutableAttributedString with additional text description as rtf file, in swift ?

Tags: swift, macos, rtf, nsmutableattributedstring

I have text as NSMutableAttributedString and I can save as rtf file. Let say in this text I have marked one line with red background color. I would like to make additional text description for this marked line. How can I save this description into rtf file to be able later to read this description and to display it in the TextView window ?

Answer (score 1):

The NSAttributedString AppKit (MacOS-only) additions includes a couple helpful methods for you:

[`RTFFromRange(_:documentAttributes:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/RTFFromRange:documentAttributes:)

[`RTFDFromRange(_:documentAttributes:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/RTFDFromRange:documentAttributes:)

These API's result in NSData objects that you can write out as RTF files.